# Вылет при запуске кода ( 2D Игра )

Tags: python, 2d, pygame

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("Cubes game")

#Player
x = 50
y = 425
width = 40
height = 60
speed = 5
isJump = False
JumpCount = 10
run = True
#Delay
while run:
    pygame.time.delay(50)
#Quit
for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False
#Keys
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 5:
        x -= speed
if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width -5:
        x += speed
if not(isJump):
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 5:
        y -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 500 - height -15:
        y += speed
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            y -= (jumpCount ** 2) / 2
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10

#Background
win.fill((0,0,0))
#Player
pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,255), (x, y, width, height))

pygame.display.update()

pygame.quit()
```

При запуске кода приложение не отвечает, все работало до того как я не добавил прыжок, помогите пожалуйста

Answer (score 1):

приложение не отвечает потому, что из `while run:` не выхода.

и еще исправьте опечатку  `JumpCount = 10`  на `jumpCount = 10`

```
import pygame

pygame.init()
win = pygame.display.set_mode((500, 500))

pygame.display.set_caption("Cubes game")

#Player
x = 50
y = 425
width = 40
height = 60
speed = 5
isJump = False
jumpCount = 10                       # JumpCount  -> jumpCount          <---------------
run = True

#Delay

#while run:                                                             # <---------------
pygame.time.delay(50)     # приостановить программу на некоторое время  # <---------------

#Quit

for event in pygame.event.get():
    if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
        run = False
#Keys
keys = pygame.key.get_pressed()
if keys[pygame.K_LEFT] and x > 5:
        x -= speed
if keys[pygame.K_RIGHT] and x < 500 - width -5:
        x += speed
if not(isJump):
    if keys[pygame.K_UP] and y > 5:
        y -= speed
    if keys[pygame.K_DOWN] and y < 500 - height -15:
        y += speed
    if keys[pygame.K_SPACE]:
        isJump = True
    else:
        if jumpCount >= -10:
            y -= (jumpCount ** 2) / 2
            jumpCount -= 1
        else:
            isJump = False
            jumpCount = 10

#Background
win.fill((0,0,0))
#Player
pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,0,255), (x, y, width, height))

pygame.display.update()

pygame.time.delay(2000) 

pygame.quit()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]